# How many clopen subsets exist in $[0,1]\cup[3,4]$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

What is the best way to prove that the subspace $[0,1]\cup[3,4]$ of $\mathbb{R}$ has exactly 4 clopen subsets- $\emptyset$,$[0,1]\cup[3,4]$, $[0,1]$ and $[3,4]$?

I divided into cases where $A\subset[0,1]$, $A\subset[3,4]$ and $A\subset[0,1]\cup[3,4]$ and $A$ is a clopen set, but is there any way other way to prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that each of $[0,1]$ and $[3,4]$ are path connected, hence connected. Thus, since they are also clopen, they must be connected components of the space. As they cover it, they are all of the connected components, and so the only clopen sets are the unions of (zero or more of) them, which are exactly the four sets that you listed.